# Heroku error on build with simple react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I tried to deploy a simple react app to heroku, 
the build was successfull but when I try to enter the site I get this error:

```
2020-04-20T20:44:15.578184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=harmonydesign.herokuapp.com request_id=03e481b0-20ee-43cd-ad51-a03af2b095d7 fwd="93.172.196.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

does anyone have an idea what this is? I have no backend or no ajax requests, the site is static.

Comment: Did you check logs in Heroku? Do you have a Procfile? Did the build succeed?

Comment: @DanaWoodman build succeded when pushed, when I enter the page I get an error and that what it said in the logs.

Comment: What kind of Heroku app is this? Static? Node? Something else? Make sure it is the right type as it may be running "npm start" which could be running your dev server. If it is static, make sure you load the Heroku "static buildpack" (google it) because Heroku might think you're trying to run a node app instead.